# Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdlxxxxxxxx.tmp: No such file or directory

Tags: android, react-native

I'm totally new to Android development.

I've been working on a react-native app, it works totally fine when running the default "react-native run-android" and "react-native run-android --variant=debug" commands.

The problem comes when running "react-native run-android --variant=release".
Logcat throws me this error:
[I've been running the emulator with different devices and the error shows in all of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR372.png)

As I previously mentioned, I don't know what this file is suppose to do and I don't know how to generate it.

I'm not sure where is it suppose to be located but I presume it is supposed to be at app-name/android/app/data/vmdlxxxxxxx.tmp. But I have no /data folder in my project.

I've been following the documentation at [the React website on publishing to Google Play Store](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android).

I don't think the keystore files are causing the problem since I've followed the steps shown to generate them, and also tried generating a .jks and assign it to the release keys to see if the output changed. I've also changed the default configs at variant release to take the same keys as in debug and as I said before, the error at logcat remains the same. So I presume this is not related to the problem.

Can someone please explain me more about it? How can I generate this missing file?

Answer (score 0):

If it is of any use for someone in the future, I was able to solve this problem by following the instructions of the following link:

[Solution](https://articles.wesionary.team/react-native-android-release-build-crashes-fa93f07a2ba4)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).